# using jQuery in a js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know by include `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` in HTML file, I can write in jQuery in this file directly. However, I am not working on a single file, thus, too much js code in the html doesn't look good. Can there be some method to use jQuery in js file? So I can put some common function in a standalone js file.

Comment: Code is ephemeral. If it works, it works. Code needs to be readable and consistent. The only aesthetics you should be worried about are the aesthetics of your actual design, not the code behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a folder with the name  **js** and inside put your js file for example **main.js**

your js file should start like : **main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //code here
});
```

note that you can use **$(document).load(function()** too

In your **index.html** put this in the footer like this : **index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <html>

      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Your Website</title>
      </head>

      <body>
        <!--============MAIN-CONTAINER============ -->
        <section>

        </section>
        <!--============SIDEBAR=================== -->
        <aside>
        </aside>
        <!--============FOOTER==================== -->
        <footer>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        </footer>

      </body>

    </html>
```

for the best performance.

**alfernative**
if you want to use it as

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

download this:

**http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js**

and put it into a new folder with the name **scripts**  and replace

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>`

with

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

in your footer like this:

```
    <footer>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put your code in your own js file :

```
$(function() {
     // your own code using the DOM

});
```

and then include this file just after the jQuery one :

```
 <script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="myownfile.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think the asker was wondering if there is a way to include jQuery in the same way you include PHP files using something along the lines of `include("example.php");`.

Comment: @Magnet I don't know. But your comment at the very least confirms the question isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use an external .js file, just add the required scripts files and their references onto your page plus add the external .js reference along with them.

```
//references in mail file
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/text.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


//External test.js file
$(document).ready(function () {
//your functions here
});                        // Document Ready Closed
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep that tag for jquery and go ahead and make your own JS file with jquery code in it and include that too in the html page, It will work