# Implementing a webservice tutorial WeatherMaps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I'm trying to include a simple Web Service to our existing web pages, and found an API and an accompanying tutorial, along with the JavaScript, CSS, and associated image files etc. and have included them in my web application.

[Here's](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/weather-web-app-geolocation-revisited/) the tutorial. [Here's](https://openweathermap.org/api) the API.

I'm using NetBeans IDE.

If I run the JavaScript to test the api,  I am hit by a

> Reference Error $ not defined

. jQuery **is** included and is at the top of my imports:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.0.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="com/WebApp/assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

Is running the js file the correct way to test that it's working?

Furthermore, even if it did run I am not too sure how to include this in my existing web page. I assume I have to copy the HTML from it's standalone index.html into the web page I wish to display the weather.

Thanks for the help

Edit: index.html cant be run so I moved the html provided to another html file and ran that. The Header and everything was displayed and the buttons for next and previous were shown, but it seems the API was never invoked because no weather showed up. I have tried calling the API by copy/pasting the URL into a browser, so I know that part is working.

It seems that the last script src = ... is the equivalent of a function call in Java, and that is definitely included in the html file I'm running but still it doesn't seem like Script.js even runs. I've put a breakpoint in there but it never stops, implying it never ran?

Any help at this point would be great

Comment: You need to run an HTML file with both javascript files included at the top. You cannot run multiple javascript files together unless you use es6, node.js, etc. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921187/using-jquery-in-a-js-file

Comment: I've included my Script.js in the index.html, but this can't be run for whatever reason. So to clarify you are asking me to create a new html file (the web page to display the result of api call), and to include the index.html and my Script.js, and then to format the webpage etc.

I only ask because you mentioned running multiple javascript files, when as far as i know there's only one.

Thanks for the response though, i appreciate it

Comment: What is a "simple run through the IDE" ? --- does it open a web browser such as chrome or firefox?

Comment: Yeah it opens the html or jsp in a browser, but I actually run it from within the IDE rather than going localhost:8080... etc, although I'm sure things would be the same either way

Comment: Check the debugger's console messages of the browser. See if there are any errors. Also you can try typing $ into the console and see if you get the same error. If you get function b() or function r() as a result from $ then something funky is going on

Comment: Also, jquery is loaded before script.js, correct? I know you said it was at the top, but the issue is usually caused by not loading it before a script that uses it...

Comment: No errors anymore since I moved the html from index.html to the form i want to display the weather on. I've done a bit of research and the line which calls the script is in there. I've edited the original post to show all the script calls in my .html file, just for a bit of clarity.